# How to approximate the distribution of the sum of multiple multinomial random variables?

Tags: poisson-distribution, multinomial-distribution, approximation, poisson-binomial-distribution

Say we have $T$ independent Multinomial random variables $X_1,X_2\dots X_T$, with $p(X_t=m)=p_{t,m},m\in\{1,2,...M\}$. What would be the distribution of $X_1+X_2+...+X_T$? If there is no closed-form, is there any approximation version of this distribution? Like, is there a multivariate version of possion-binomial distribution?

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which $X_1+\cdots + X_N$ could be considered "multivariate"?  One wonders whether you use the term "Multinomial random variables" in the standard sense of, say, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: Your question is ambiguous/unclear. If you're summing the counts in a subset of the categories for a single multinomial, the sum will be binomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) in the usual sense (in which case you should correct the range to include zero.)  Then: If the probability parameter $p=(p_1, \dotsc, p_k)$ are all equal, then the sum is also multinomial. If they are unequal, then we have the situation that in the binomial $k=2$ case leads to Poisson-Binomial distribution, and in the multinomial case is known as (surprise!) Poisson-Multinomial. Here is a relevant [math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164222/generalizing-poissons-binomial-distribution-to-the-multinomial-case).

Comment: Hi Kjetil, could you explain why the range should include zero?